# Probabilistic model- two approaches

Tags: probability, probability-theory

let us imagine that we roll with two dices. We can imagine that we throw one dice, and then another. Then we can make the following probability model i.e. the $\Omega$ set:

$\Omega=\{(i,j),\,i,j\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\}$.

Okay, but can we see this situation in this way?: we roll this dices together and we do not know which dice is "first" and which is the "second" i.e.:

$\Omega=\{\{i,j\},\,i,j\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\}$.

The probability of events will be of course different. Is the second model realistic? What do you think?

Comment: Using your second sample space, how do you denote the outcome of 'doubles'? (E.g., if for instance both dice come up $4$.)

Comment: I do not understad: cannot we write $\{4,4\}$? Ohhh... I get it now ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second case you *could* use your second version of  $\ \Omega\ $ as your sample space, but you could also use the first, because real physical dice are *always* distinguishable upon a sufficiently close examination, even if your naked eye can't discern any difference.

If you use your second sample space, then (assuming the faces that come up are independent) the probabilities you assign to the elements of $\ \Omega\ $ would have to take the form
\begin{align}
P(\{i\})&= p_{1i}p_{2i}&\text{for }\ i\in\{1,2,\dots,6\}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \\
P(\{i,j\})&=p_{1i}p_{2j}+p_{1j}p_{2i} &\text{for }\ i,j\in\{1,2,\dots,6\}\ \text{with }\ i\ne j\ ,
\end{align}
where $\ p_{1j}\ $ is the probability that face $\ j\ $ comes up on one of the dice (which you may call "the first", if you so wish), and $\ p_{2j}\ $ is the probability that face $\ j\ $ comes up on the other.